# Mule dw:transform-message jax parse exception

Tags: mule

I have an issue. Deployed to runtime my mule XML file.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1836) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:647) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:582) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2171) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
        ... 52 more
org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 15 in XML document from testmule.xml is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 111; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dw:transform-message'.
```

Dear mule experts. Schema file is missing for dw.xsd

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mavenized project add data-weave dependency as

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Also check whether your xml has schemaLocation entry in mule base tag as

```
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
```

and

```
xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw"
```

Comment: Hi this is in pom file. My xml is containing schema loc also and namespace is defined for dw? have you another idea why is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the mule.tools.version to 1.1`<mule.tools.version>1.1</mule.tools.version>` and mule.version and mule.munit.support.version should be same for maven to update all the weave related dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I try to go to `http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd` in a browser I get a 404. Browsing around I can get up to `http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/` there is no `dw` folder. Which may be there reason my tests are failing.